# Load External javascript, but HTTP request repeatedly for one file javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem when load external html into specific `<div>`. Here is the problem :

1. I have html files, `"index.html"` and `"problem.html"`.
2. In problem.html I use [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to animate content.
3. When I click the "open" button in index.html, I use jquery `load()` method to load problem.html into specific  in index.html.
4. The content was loading, but slowly.
5. When I check using firebug, I see many request `skrollr.min.js`. Why do I get `skrollr.min.js` and other file repeatedly?

When I refresh the page, load the menu and see at the firebug there are so many get `skrollr.min.js` and file that are called.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the Page via iframe to see if it's faster. Just set the innerHTML of your container to

```
<iframe src="http://yourdomain.com/problem.html"></iframe>
```

when he clicked the Button.

Comment: but i want it load to specific div. Should i load problem.html to iframe when i clicked so there is no more request repeatedly ?? Sorry im beginer on javascript.

Comment: Yea. It could also be a problem with JS or how you use it. Maybe also your Server, it can have multiple reasons. But since doing it with the basics of HTML it should load faster (probably).
And you can load it into a spcific div. Give your div an id, like #prob and change the innerHTML -> Example: document.getElementById("prob").innerHTML="<iframe ...";